# WSL translate W10 CLI switches into Linux?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, command-line-arguments, veracrypt

I'm trying to install Veracrypt and run it (mount volumes, etc.) from a script run in WSL (Python but can call a BASH script obviously).

As documented [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/636749/220752), I've encountered a problem trying to use the Linux console version of Veracrypt. So then I thought maybe I can use the fact that in WSL you can run Windows apps too. And the W10 version of Veracrypt can indeed be run from the CLI. For example, this works:

```
> "VeraCrypt.exe" /v e:\test.vc /l A /password "badger34" /silent /q
```

How, if at all, might those W10-style switches "translate" into WSL switches? Here are a few attempts:

```
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ "VeraCrypt.exe" /v e:\test.vc /l A /password "badger34" /silent /q
VeraCrypt.exe: command not found
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ ./VeraCrypt.exe /v e:\test.vc /l A /password "badger34" /silent /q
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ ./VeraCrypt.exe /v e:\test.vc /l A /password "badger34" /q
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ ./VeraCrypt.exe /v /mnt/e/test.vc /l A /password "badger34" /q
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ ./VeraCrypt.exe -v /mnt/e/test.vc -l A /password "badger34" -q
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ ./VeraCrypt.exe "/v /mnt/e/test.vc /l A /password \"badger34\" /q"
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ ./VeraCrypt.exe /v /mnt/e/test.vc /l A /password "badger34" /q
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ ./VeraCrypt.exe --v /mnt/e/test.vc --l A --password "badger34" --q
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ ./VeraCrypt.exe -v /mnt/e/test.vc -l A -password "badger34" -q
```

Mostly Veracrypt responds with an error dialog, e.g. "Error parsing command line" ... in example 5 the Veracrypt GUI dialog comes up.

In fact the above are unlikely to work, for the simple reason that in Linux you mount with a mount point in the file system, not a drive letter (which doesn't yet exist... though if it did it would be `/mnt/a` in the above).

```
./VeraCrypt.exe /v /mnt/e/test.vc /l /mnt/a /password 'badger34' /q
./VeraCrypt.exe /v /mnt/e/test.vc /l /media/mike/rsync_vc_drive_e /password 'badger34' /q
```

Make that drive letter location???

```
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ sudo mkdir /mnt/a
[sudo] password for m17awl:
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ ./VeraCrypt.exe /v /mnt/e/test.vc /l /mnt/a /password 'badger34' /q
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ ./VeraCrypt.exe /v /mnt/e/test.vc /l A /password 'badger34' /q
```

--> "Error parsing command line"

NB if you run `veracrypt.exe /?` in the W10 command prompt you get a list of available switches.

Any ideas? I don't suppose, for example, there's some way of passing a "pure W10" CLI line outside the WSL environment and into the W10 environment and running it?

Comment: This just work in my case `cmd.exe /c echo` without any trickery.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's frustrating because if you put an incorrect path after the `/v` option it complains about that, so some aspects of the command line are being accepted correctly... hmmm

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
m17awl@M17A:/mnt/d/apps/VeraCrypt$ cmd.exe /K mount_a.bat
D:\apps\VeraCrypt>"VeraCrypt.exe" /v e:\test.vc /l A /password "badger34" /silent /q 
D:\apps\VeraCrypt>
```

... and after a second or two drive A: appears e.g. in Explorer. Hurrah.

NB only the first line was entered by me, i.e. where mount_a.bat contains my Plain-Old-W10 command line. This also ends the WSL process in question (or otherwise transforms it into a W10 process), but that's not a problem.

There may be a better answer than this. Also this then leads to another problem (which occurs even when I mount "manually" in W10, using the VC GUI app): there is no way to access the drive (i.e. /mnt/a in the above example does not exist!). But this is a different problem of course.